# PostgreSQL: After Removing PostgreSQL 12 psql version 12.2 still persists

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

With Ubuntu Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 Postgres was updated to 12.

I did remove Postgres 12 with

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-12
```

to go back to Postgres Version 9.3 (I know it's outdated and upgrade highly recommended and it's planned within a few weeks)

But I noticed psql is still on version 12.2.

How can I revert psql version to 9.3?

Comment: You probably need to remove `postgresql-12-client` (or a similar name) as well.

Comment: after removing postgresql-client-12 I get the error message "Error: PostgreSQL version 12 is not installed" whenever I run psql. An (re-)installation of postgresql-client-9.3 doesn't change this behaviour. Do I have to symlink psql in /usr/bin/ to /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql  ?